# How do I place focus on an element in dojo that only has a class and not an id

Tags: javascript, focus

I have a textarea where it only allows 150 characters how do I make the focus go from the textarea to the error message after a user exceeds the maximum number of characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must set an identity for the element and then execute `document.getElementById('elementId').focus()`.
If you have troubles with double used id's, then declare a global variable with a sequence number and increase this number (and use it as part of the element id) every time.